# What are the conditions for solution of nonlinear Fredholm equations with Banach fixed point theorem?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

Consider the nonlinear Fredholm integral equation of the second kind:
$$
\varphi(x) = f(x) + \lambda \int_a^b F(x, t, \varphi(t)) \, dt
$$
where

- $(f)$ and $(K)$ are given functions,
- $(a, b)$ are constants, and
- $(\varphi)$ is the unknown function.

The associated nonlinear Fredholm operator for this integral equation is:
$$
T(\varphi)(x) = f(x) + \lambda \int_a^b K(x, t, \varphi(t)) \, dt
$$
Using the Banach Fixed Point Theorem, I want to establish necessary conditions for the existence of a solution of the nonlinear Fredholm equation in this case, where $K:[a, b] \times[a, b] \times[-R, R] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I know I have to check that Fredholm operator satisfies the following requirements:

1. it is well defined
2. $(T(\varphi)$ is a continuous function for every continuous function $\varphi$
3. $T$ is a contraction, and I checked this since
   $$
   |T(\varphi_1)- T(\varphi_2)|=|\lambda|\left|\int_a^bK(x,t,\varphi_1)-\int_a^bK(x,t,\varphi_2)\right|.
   $$
4. $T$ is invariant.
5. $T$ satisfies all the hypotheses of the Banach Fixed-Point Theorem.

But now I'm really stuck any help?

Comment: I guess the following. In the first equation should be $K$ instead of $F$. Next, the Banach Fixed Point Theorem should be used to establish *sufficient* conditions for the existence of a solution of the nonlinear Fredholm equation. Next, the classes of the considered functions should be clarified, like $f,\phi\in L_2[a,b]$ and $K\in L_2[a,b]^2$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky well the excursive just say that no more information

Comment: Hello, I believe there are many experts in fixed point theory here who can help. But not everyone is familiar with the terminology of non-linear Fredholm equations.  For example, you could better describe the domain of the $T$ operator. Is $C^{0}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the norm of $\|\varphi\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|\varphi(x)|$ ? Would $C^{0}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ be equipped with the norm of $\|\varphi\|_{L_{p}}=\int_0^1|\varphi(t)|^p dt $ ?

Comment: What would $T$ invariant mean?  Would it mean that there exists a ball $B$ in the domain of $T$ such that $T(B)\subset B$?